# Update automatically column field

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, data-binding, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a gridcontrol which is binded to a list using a `BindingSource`.

```
invoice_GroupListBindingSource.Datasource= _list.
GridControl.DataSource = invoice_GroupListBindingSource
```

Now there is one checkedit column (let's call it `Invoice_Bool`). The functionality requirement is when user select anyone of he column all the datarows should be updated and select column for them should also be selected.

Foloowing is the code I tried:

```
private void invoice_GroupListBindingSource_CurrentItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Data.InvoiceGroupList.InvoiceGroupInfo current;
            if (invoice_GroupListBindingSource.Current == null)
            {
                current = null;
            }
            else
            {
                current = ((Data.InvoiceGroupList.InvoiceGroupInfo)invoice_GroupListBindingSource.Current);
            }

           if (current.Invoice_Bool)
                {
                    foreach (var item in _invoice_list)
                    {
                        item.Invoice_Bool = true;
                    }
                    this.invoice_GroupListBindingSource.DataSource = _invoice_list;

                }
        }
```

With this I am getting an updated list with all the `Invoice_Bool` true when user selects any of them (as required), however in the front-end(in the grid) all the bool values are still unselected. Any idea how to update the grid also when data source changes.. ideally it should be done automatically but I am not sure why it is not updating.

Comment: Are the changes being saved to the DB but it's just the grid that's not refreshing?

Comment: No..changes are not being saved in DB. Invoice_Bool doesn't exists in DB. I am just taking the list of all invoices from DB and when user clicks on Invoice_Bool a new invoice form opens for the selected Invoice.(where he can make changes to selected invoices)

Comment: Run the designer for the grid and look at the columns that are populated.  Find `Invoice_Bool` and look at the RepositoryEditItem for that column.  If there isn't one, then add one of type `CheckEdit`.  Within those properties, you can set what the EditValue `Type` is.  Try changing that to `bool` and see if that works.  We use these CheckEdit's for integer values and it's great b/c we can set it to true or false based on a number (ie. if it's 10 then true or if it's 20 then it's false).